# Unexpected indent in Python function

Tags: python, indentation

I want that my function returns encoding. User should import it. However, if a user hits enter, the function should return windows-1250 as default encoding.

When I run this code I get an error:

> if enc == '':
>   ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent

```
def encoding_code(prompt):
    """
    Asks for an encoding,
    throws an error if not valid encoding.
    Empty string is by default windows-1250.
    Returns encoding.
    """
    while True:
        enc = raw_input(prompt)
        if enc == '':
            enc = 'windows-1250'

        try:
            tmp = ''.decode(enc) # Just to throw an error if not correct
        except:
            print('Wrong input. Try again.')
            continue
        break
    return enc
```

Comment: You are most probably mixing tabs and spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces.

Before **if**, you have used one space and two tabs.

In Python, you should not be mixing tabs and spaces. You should use either **tabs** or **spaces**.

You can find that using `python -tt script.py`.

Most of the Python developers prefer *spaces* to *tabs*.

Comment: I used Atom but the code was writen in Sublime. Now I converted all the code from tabs to spaces. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Explanation for the double "t", `-tt`. [For `-t`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/python) (my emphasis): *"Issue a warning when a source file mixes tabs and spaces for indentation in a way that makes it depend on the worth of a tab expressed in spaces.* ***Issue an error when the option is given twice."***

Answer (score 1):

Python generally requires you to have the same level of indents in your code (generally multiples of 4 spaces, which is basically the same as a single tab).

```
def encoding_code(prompt):
    """
    Asks for an encoding,
    throws an error if not valid encoding.
    Empty string is by default windows-1250.
    Returns encoding.
    """
    while True:
        enc = raw_input(prompt)
        if enc == '':
            enc = 'windows-1250'

        try:
            tmp = ''.decode(enc) # Just to throw an error if not correct
        except:
            print('Wrong input. Try again.')
            continue
        break
     return enc
```

Comment: Four spaces are not the same as a single tab. How many spaces a tab counts for depends entirely on conventions and editor settings. A tab may even be worth varying amounts of spaces, depending on the column it starts on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @mkrieger1 you're right. But many Python IDEs by default set a tab as 4 spaces. But correct, it doesn't have to be 4 spaces.

Also, in several IDEs, if you're in a column between multiples of 4, tab takes you to the next column that is a multiple of 4.